# android Navigation Tabs in middle of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-tabs

In my app i want to have tabs in the middle of the screen and a gMap at the top is there anyway to position the tabs in the middle of the screen?

Here is a raw design

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [qnex.me](http://nairdat.qnex.me/ab_tabs.png))</sub>

Comment: Related, without using library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417209/android-tabs-in-middle-of-layout/36796343#36796343

Comment: @RominaV Your solution shows the tab, but the Fragment contents shows up empty and the swipe actions does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ViewPagerIndicator library (using TabPageIndicator control) with a ViewPager control, and these are completely separate from the ActionBar and can be positioned anywhere you like.  Download the source and check out the sample app.  The code is very straightforward.

Here's an example straight from the source of the sample app

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/simple_tabs.xml