# Android Tabs in middle of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs

In the middle of my layout I want to have 2 tabs to choose between viewing 2 different lists in the second half of the screen. How can I do this?

Here is an image illustrating what I wish to achieve. This image has a questions tab and an answers tab in the middle of the screen. Depending on which tab you select it shows a different listview:

[image: TabExample]

I wish to achieve this exact same thing.

I tried doing it with TabHost widget, but for the life of me I couldn't get rid of the title bar (I tried selecting themes with no title bar, tried setting the theme in the manifest to a no title bar one)

I also tried make action bar tabs, but those were at the top of the screen....

How can I create tabs in the middle of my screen like in the image?

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question to be more clear in what you are asking?

Comment: @Cookster Just edited the question. Essentially what I want to do is make tabs in the middle of my screen, but I can't figure out how. I would like for someone to explain how.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do the same today! I tried with `PagerTabStrip`, because I thought you can't use `TabLayout` if it's not with a `Toolbar`. Turns out I was wrong, and it's even used in [Google iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/2531cbdbe27e5795eb78bf47d27e8c1be494aad4/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_my_schedule_narrow.xml). So you can put a `TabLayout` + `ViewPager` wherever you want.

I know you want to do some very custom tabs, which would be easier to customize if they were buttons, but in my opinion it's better to use `TabLayout` + `ViewPager`, since it makes things more scalable.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/pager_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TournamentWaitingTimerTabTextAppearance" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pager_header"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the viewpager in activity_main.xml
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new LeftFragment(), "Players");
        adapter.addFrag(new RightFragment(), "Prizes");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.pager_header);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the adapter you use, it doesn't matter.

To customize tabs, I'd take a look at [this amazing tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/).

Comment: Thanks for reply, in my activity it shows tab bar but it do not shows fragment content, can you guess what's the problem?

Comment: Fragment content shows empty and swipe action does not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)

You can add fragments as page tabs by implementing a FragmentPagerAdapter

In your layout xml file, you should be able to move around the ViewPager to anywhere in your layout like you would most other components. I haven't tried centering it, but I have placed things above and below it, and it behaves as you would expect.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:id="@+id/pager"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

FragmentPagerAdapter example

```
 public class FragmentPagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

    private final String[] PAGE_TITLES =
            {
                    "Fragment1",
                    "Fragment2"
            };

    public FragmentPagerAdapter()
    {
        super(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return PAGE_TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
}
```

and in your main Acivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

...    
        mCustomPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter();
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

...
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to copy the code you have, but getSupportFragmentManager() seems to be undefined. I was googling it and it seems you have to inherit from fragmentActivity, however we already extend FragmentPageAdapter...

Comment: Good point...My project that I took the code from has FragmentPagerAdapter located as a nested class of the MainActivity. Try to place the class inside the activity you wish to use it.